# Why do bread companies add sugar to bread?

Tags: substitutions, bread, sugar, salt, flour

I have a client who is on a sugar detox/diet. She can't eat any bread because all the bread companies added sugar. Why do bread companies add sugar to their breads?

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the ... awkward title of the question: Adding sugar instead of other sweeting agents to bread can have several reasons:

- flavour (caramelization)
- texture of the crumb (substituting sugar with another sweetening agent has a big impact on the chewiness of some chocolate cookies. I'm not sure whether the effect of adding sugar to bread has such a great effect)
- texture of the crust (caramelization)
- appearance (caramelization makes the crust look browner)
- "food" for the yeast that makes the dough rise (if yeast is used as a baking agent at all)

Or - in case that the bread is really, really sweet: shelf life.

Comment: The sugar can only caramelize in any significant quantity when the temperature well exceeds 212 F / 100 C, which *only* happens in the crust.  While it may contribute flavor throughout the loaf, that flavor is simply sweetness, not caramel notes except in the crust.   Sugar can affect the structure of baked goods, but is unlikely to be used in sufficient quantities in a yeast raised bread.  So really, only your last two bullet points apply.